# How can I fix "dpkg: error: parsing file"?

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, gwibber

I am very new to Linux, and am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

All updates are failing with

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' 
near line 2 package 'libgwibber-gtk2': 
value for `status' field not allowed in this context Error in function:
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to reset the dpkg available status

Please open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and enter the following commands line-by-line:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update
```